# Out of box PCI Compliant solutions for user authentication and logging in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, log4net, pci-compliance

We have an admin website which is essentially a user interface for our clients to look at their customer transactions and reports. This is developed on ASP.net MVC3 using Telerik MVC controls. The main crux of our product are the webservices. We are looking at getting us PCI compliant. The authentication on the website is not at all secure, there is no custom membership or forms authentication. We store the hashed passwords in the database. I wanted to see if there are any out of box third party "PCI Compliant" libraries which can be used to do the user authentication? if not what is the best way to achieve PCI Compliance within membership?

Also, we currently use the open source log4net for logging for both the website as well as the webservices. Is there some other "Logging" solution which is PCI compliant?? It will be best if the logging can be used both at the product level and network level.

Appreciate all the help.

Thanks,
SDD

Answer (score 0):

In regards to authentication PCI requires that all passwords are encrypted or hashed with hashing being the easiest implementation.

Avoid using MD5.  I suggest to use PBKDF2. Look at http://code.google.com/p/stackid/source/browse/OpenIdProvider/Current.cs#1135 for some reference code that stackoverflow is actually using as well.

Log4net is fine for logging but you will need to use the UdpAppender to send logs to a syslog server.  Make sure you log at least what is required by PCI logging requirements and make sure you do not log any passwords or credit card numbers.